# PHP CURL not working but works when copy pasted

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I was sending a request to one of the sms gateway providers with HTTP API.

But I am getting 403 Forbidden error. 
    `Forbidden You don't have permission to access API/WebSMS/Http/v1.0a/index.php on this server.`

My code:-

```
$url="http://www.somesite.in/API/WebSMS/Http/v1.0a/index.php?username=".$GLOBALS['smsGatewayUsername']."&password=".$GLOBALS['smsGatewayPassword']."&sender=".$GLOBALS['smsGatewaySenderId']."&to=".$mobileNumber."&message=".$message."&reqid=1&format=text&route_id=".$GLOBALS['smsGatewayRouteId']."&sendondate=".$GLOBALS['dateCustom']."&msgtype=unicode";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
```

But the `$url` works when cop pasted in the browser.

I have enabled the `extension=php_curl.dll` inside xampp php.ini

Comment: May be coz the session was once created with the browser, so its working. Clear cookies and session of that site from the browser and try the same url again. And they must have implemented some authentication method, you need to pass that in curl.

Comment: This is not a php/curl error. The server simply says that you are not allowed to send this request. You have echoed the `$url` and checked this in the browser?

Comment: Try to urlencode your `$url` before sending it with curl.

Comment: All the authentication  parameter are passed in URL. When i echo and paste the url in browser it works fine. I have cleared cache cookies and sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and got the code to work. Instead of passing the parameter as an URL, passed it as postfield option in CURL.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.somesite.in/API/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=".$GLOBALS['smsGatewayUsername']."&password=".$GLOBALS['smsGatewayPassword']."&sender=".$GLOBALS['smsGatewaySenderId']."&to=".$mobileNumber."&message=".$message."&reqid=1&format=text&route_id=".$GLOBALS['smsGatewayRouteId']."&sendondate=".$GLOBALS['dateCustom']."&msgtype=unicode");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```